# Send notification

Tags: facebook, notifications, message

Currently Facebook allows you send notifications by app?

The notification which I refer is that on the top bar to the left side, as the image:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/824/img2a.png/

Some posts says that has been disabled because of spam, others say it is deprecated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Facebook said: ["Beginning next Monday, March 1, 2010, at 10AM Pacific time, Facebook will no longer deliver application notifications and will discontinue support for notifications.send."](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/365)

Comment: I have seen a website pininterest still sending notifications how does it manage to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Those red notifications can be sent from one user to another using the [app requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).  There isn't currently a way to send them from your server/app directly to the user though.